# Restrinct action to one single PC under MVC C# web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization

It's possible to restrict one Action from my asp.net mvc website to a single PC while the entire website can be accessed by any PC?

Comment: Why is a restriction on PC needed?

Comment: It's a client request.

Comment: Give the client's login/user a special role. Same outcome and they won't yell at you when they inevitably want to use the app from something else.

Comment: It MUST be one single PC.. can't be by login or some other restriction that give the capability to access from another place

Comment: You can't identify a PC. Best you could do is identify the IP the request is coming from. However the IP could be identifying a whole range of devices. IPs also change frequently.

Comment: And if the filter is made by the public IP?

Comment: Would work, yes, but the problems are that the public IP doesn't identify a single device. The IP can change at the ISPs will, breaking your app. And now spoofing is on the table as a security risk.